# I'm unable to show notifcation in reactjs app I'm using react-redux-notify

Tags: reactjs, redux

I'm using `react-redux-notify` to show notification in my app. I'm using a functional component for my app. I have followed all the guide given on their Github repo. I have shared my code below.

**combineReducers.js**

```js
import { combineReducers } from 'redux';
import notifyReducer from 'react-redux-notify';
import reducer from './reducer';

export default combineReducers({
  rootReducer: reducer,
  notifications: notifyReducer,
});
```

I have included that reducer in my store

**My component code**

```
import React from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { Notify } from 'react-redux-notify';
import {
  createNotification,
  NOTIFICATION_TYPE_SUCCESS,
} from 'react-redux-notify';

const mySuccessNotification = {
  message: 'You have been logged in!',
  type: NOTIFICATION_TYPE_SUCCESS,
  duration: 0,
  canDismiss: true,
  icon: <i className="fa fa-check" />,
};

function createRestaurantSetup(props) {
  function changeState() {
    console.log('state event called');
    createNotification(mySuccessNotification);
  }

  return (
    <div className={classes.root}>
      <Notify />

      <Button type="submit" size="small" color="primary" onClick={changeState}>
        Start Setting
      </Button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

I'm not getting any error in `changeState` function. But the notification is also not showing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code example is not entirely correct. I've looked at the guide on the Github for react-redux-notify. It has a lot of errors and weird code examples, so I see it's easy to get confused.

Your code has the following issues:

**Connect**
You're first of all need to connect your component to your redux store with `connect`. I'm not sure if you're doing it, but it's missing in the code you provided.

**createNotification**
This is where the code examples in the guide get confusing. The `createNotification` is an action that you import from react-redux-notify, just like you're doing. But it's not a method that you can call directly from the component. In redux, actions have to be dispatched from the component. So what you're missing is the `dispatch` method that can be retrieved from the component props, when you've connected it to the store. The guide for react-redux-notify suggests using `mapDispatchToProps` which is a way of binding a method to dispatch a given action directly to the props of the component.

So your component code should like this:

```
import React from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { Notify } from 'react-redux-notify';
import {
  createNotification,
  NOTIFICATION_TYPE_SUCCESS,
} from 'react-redux-notify';

const mySuccessNotification = {
  message: 'You have been logged in!',
  type: NOTIFICATION_TYPE_SUCCESS,
  duration: 0,
  canDismiss: true,
  icon: <i className="fa fa-check" />,
};

function createRestaurantSetup(props) {
  function changeState() {
    const { dispatchNotification } = props;

    dispatchNotification(mySuccessNotification);
  }

  return (
    <div className={classes.root}>
      <Notify />

      <Button type="submit" size="small" color="primary" onClick={changeState}>
        Start Setting
      </Button>
    </div>
  );
};

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => ({
  dispatchNotification: (config) => dispatch(createNotification(config)),
});

export default connect(null, mapDispatchToProps)(createRestaurantSetup);
```

Unlike the guide on the github, I renamed the `createNotifcation` prop to `dispatchNotification` so it's easier to differentiate the two. The code for the reducer should be fine.

Hope this helps